# How to create generic method returning different types extending the same parent

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, generics, switch-statement

I have created method like this:

```
public BaseMenu openMenu(MenuItem menuItem) {
        utils.clickOnElement(menuItem);
        BaseMenu baseMenu = null;

        switch (menuItem) {
            case FIRST:
                baseMenu = new FirstMenu();
                break;
            case SECOND:
                baseMenu = new SecondMenu();
                break;
            case THIRD:
                baseMenu = new ThirdMenu();
                break;
        }
        return baseMenu;
    }
```

It returns type BaseMenu. How to convert it, so that it would return specific menu types (which are extending BaseMenu), like FirstMenu, SecondMenu, etc.?

I tried something like that:

```
public <T extends BaseMenu> T openMenu(MenuItem menuItem) {
        utils.clickOnElement(menuItem);
        T baseMenu = null;

        switch (menuItem) {
            case FIRST:
                baseMenu = (T) new FirstMenu();
                break;
            case SECOND:
                baseMenu = (T) new SecondMenu();
                break;
            case THIRD:
                baseMenu = (T) new ThirdMenu();
                break;
        }
        return baseMenu;
    }
```

but it also returned BaseMenu.

How should code look like to work as I am expecting? Is it possible to do it this way? Is there any other way to achieve it?

EDIT:

How am I use it now:

```
FirstMenu firstMenu = new MainPage().getSomeElementContainingMenu().openMenu(FIRST);

firstMenu.doSomethingFromFirstMenu();
```

How I want to use it:

```
new MainPage().getSomeElementContainingMenu().openMenu(FIRST).doSomethingFromFirstMenu(); 
//where result of openMenu(specificMenu) will be new SpecificMenu(), not BaseMenu() like now
```

It doesn't have to be based on switch, it was my initial idea, which I have shared here, but it doesn't work as I thought, so I would gladly see also
other possible solutions.

Comment: I can't make out what you're actually trying to solve for.. you have an enum to translate a choice into a different object type, to then call a constructor to return the object to the caller. What is the actual usage scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert this function. Returning `BaseMenu` was a valid solution which described your use case. It should be the caller's responsibility to cast it to the required type if needed.

The main idea of a generic you let the caller determine the type of the generic so your function can focus on the parts you really cares about. So if I call that function and state that I want that generic to be a class I implemented myself, your function will need to use it.

For example, this code sample would be a valid usage of the generic version.

```java
class Foo extends BaseMenu { /* etc. */ }

Foo foo = openMenu(menuItem);
```

Alternatively, it may make more sense if you also add methods for `firstMenu`, `secondMenu`, etc. You should really only be selecting the menu  this way if you only need to use functionality all `BaseMenu`s implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends BaseMenu> T openMenu(MenuItem menuItem) {
    utils.clickOnElement(menuItem);
    T baseMenu = null;
    
    switch (menuItem) {
        case FIRST:
            baseMenu = new FirstMenu();
            break;
        case SECOND:
            baseMenu = new SecondMenu();
            break;
        case THIRD:
            baseMenu = new ThirdMenu();
            break;
    }
    return (T) baseMenu;
}
```

when you call this method! you must use like this:

FirstMenu fm = openMenu(menuItem);

you should not use :

BaseMenu bm = openMenu(menuItem);

cause your method return value is T, that T type is what you handle that return value, if you use BaseMenu to take that return value, that T will be BaseMenu!!